# ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Discord' before initialization

Tags: javascript, discord

when i try to load my javascript script this error appear (also it's for a discord bot)

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Discord' before initialization
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\33614\Desktop\spambot.js\index.js:1:16)
[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)[39m
[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)[39m
[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)[39m
[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)[39m
[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47[39m
```

Also my code

```
const client = Discord.client(); 
const Discord = require("discord.js"); 

var prefix = '!' 
var token = 'NzM1NjI4OTEzMzY3MDU2NDA0.XxnRyQ.X2H-FP1DSRq97DoyRtYnEpqmI5s' 

client.on("ready", function() { 
    console.log("ready") 
}) 

client.on("message", message => {

 }) 
 
 client.login(token);
```

Comment: You try to access it on line 1. You initialise it on line 2. 1 is before 2. The error message is quite clear.

Comment: ```const client = Discord.client(); 
const Discord = require("discord.js"); ``` 
just swap them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first two lines look like they should be switched around - first "import", then use.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js"); 
const client = Discord.Client();
```

As per the docs:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'ping') {
    msg.reply('Pong!');
  }
});

client.login('token');
```

Comment: `Discord.Client()`. Watch the capital **C**.

Comment: Thanks.Your answer will be accepted in 6 mins